# no Ipfp function after installing mipfp

Tags: r, installation, package

I just installed a package called mipfp in my R.  However when I tried to run the below command, I was prompted there is no function such as Ipfp:

```
`InitialM <- array(1,dim=c(5,5))
for(i in 1:5) {
  InitialM[i,i] <- 0
}

SumOfRows <- c(40, 60, 20, 10, 10)
SumOfCols <- c(30, 30, 60, 10, 10)
TargetData<- list(SumOfRows, SumOfCols)
Target.list <- list(1,2)
RandomMatrix <- Ipfp(InitialM, Target.list, TargetData, 
                     iter=100, tol=1e-10)
```

I even tried the lower case, ipfp with no success. Has any of you run into this problem?  How can I resolve this?  I would really appreciate any suggestion to move forward on this.

Thank you,
Soyoko

Comment: Probable instance of not loading an installed package. See R-FAQ item 7.30:https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#I-installed-a-package-but-the-functions-are-not-there Almost certainly a duplicate of prior SO question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did the install succeed with out errors?

Can you check if the function is available to your workspace

```
?Ipfp
```

Should return the help for the function

is the library loaded?

```
library(mipfp)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It was the library.  This is amazing I have gotten an answer so quickly to get out of this rut.  Thank you so so much!!